# Atlas for the closed ball.

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, stokes-theorem, manifolds-with-boundary

Consider the manifold with boundary $$D:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \Vert x \Vert  \leq 1\}$$

I want to calculate $$\int_D dx \wedge dy$$

using the definition of the integral.

The integral is defined this way in my book:

> Assume we have a manifold $M$ of dimension $m$. We will define $\int_M
>  \omega$ where $\omega$ is a compactly supported $m$-form (i.e.
>   $\operatorname{supp}(\omega) := \overline{\{p \in M\mid \omega(p) \neq
>  0\}}$ is compact)
>
> (Step 1): Assume $\operatorname{supp}(\omega) \subseteq U$ for some
>   chart $(U, \phi)$. Write $$(\phi^{-1})^*(\omega) = f dx_1 \land \dots
>  \land dx_m \in \Omega(\phi(U))$$  where $f \in C^\infty(\phi(U))$.
>   Define $$\int_M \omega := \int_{\phi(U)}f$$
>
> where the right integral is an ordinary Riemann-integral.
>
> (Step 2): Involves a partition of unity to define the general case and
>   I don't think it is important here so I'll ommit it.

I want to use this definition to calculate the above integral, so the first issue I'm stumbling upon. What is an atlas for $D$? I guess, I can just consider the map $id_D: D \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and this is an atlas for $D$? My confusion is the following: Formally, a chart is a map $U \to V$ where $V$ is an open in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ or some $\mathbb{H}^n$, so aren't there actually two charts involved (one for the interior, another for the boundary?)

If I can just pick the identity as one chart, then $$\int_D dx \land dy := \int_D dxdy = \pi$$

Any advice?

Comment: Your $D$ is a 3D ball and your form is a $2$-form, so the integral is not defined. You probably want to integrate it over the surface only, i.e. over the sphere. In that case, a chart that covers (almost) all of the sphere is given by the [standard spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) (with $r=1$). You do not need an atlas and partition of unity since the part not covered has zero area and does not contribute to the integral. Besides, using partition of unity is not very realistic in practical computations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It was actually a disk in the plane, not in $3$-space; I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: If it is the disk use polar coordinates with $0<r<1$, $0<\theta<2\pi$. Again, a single chart covers almost all of the disk.

Comment: It is the disk, but the interior is also in the disk? What chart are you exactly using?

Comment: The interior is covered except for $[0,1)$ segment on the real axis. You can also use the open disk itself, with Cartesian coordinates, as the chart (the boundary has zero area), but then the limits of integration are unpleasant.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate in an answer? I'm still not quite getting it.

Comment: Let me say something general about your question. The definition you quote for the integral of a differential form has many theoretical advantages but, except for extremely simple cases, cannot be used for explicit calculations. The reason is that finding explicit partitions of unity is not very practical so the only case where you can "use the definition" to calculate an integral is the case where the form is supported in some chart. This is **not** the case for your manifold and form. So in any case you need to use some theorem which allows you to calculate the integral differently and not

Comment: rely on the definition. The closed disk, as a manifold with boundary, can be covered by one chart "up to" a set of measure zero (the boundary of the disc) and you can prove that if this is the case, one can calculate the integral of the form over that chart "using the formula" in step (1) and get the correct result **even though** the form is not compactly supported in the interior of the chart. Those issues are somewhat subtle and often ignored in weak or beginner's textbooks.

Comment: @levap How does one calculate integrals explicitely then?

Comment: @user661541: This depends on the situation. In your case, there is a chart (in fact, many charts) which covers the manifold up to a set of measure zero. You use one such chart to pull back the differential form to the domain and integrate just like you would integrate a function. This is what Conifold did in his answer using a polar coordinates chart but you can also use the identity chart and calculate the result using Fubini or change of variables. I'm just saying that this is not considered "calculation directly from the definition" but is based on various theorems that say this is legit.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $U=(0,1)\times(0,2\pi)$, and $\varphi(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$. Then integrating over $D$ is equivalent to integrating over $\phi(U)$ because $D\backslash\phi(U)$ has zero area, and

$$\int_{\phi(U)}dx \land dy=\int_{U}\phi^*(dx \land dy)=\int_{U}d(r\cos\theta)\land d(r\sin\theta)\\=\int_{U}rdr\land d\theta=\int_0^1\!rdr\int_0^{2\pi}\!\!\!\!d\theta=\frac12\cdot2\pi=\pi.$$

If we integrate in Cartesian coordinates then $U=\textrm{int}D$ and $\varphi(x,y)=(x,y)$. There is no need for the boundary chart since the boundary area is $0$, and it makes no contribution to the integral. So $\int_{\phi(U)}dx \land dy=\int_Ddx\,dy$. But unless we just assume that the area is $\pi$ the actual integration is unpleasant.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if I can understand!

Comment: @user661541 How did it go?

Comment: Very good! Thanks again.